# How to edit an object inside an array or how to structure it

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a project management application where projects will have features and users can comment on the features, I am using react with firestore. now I am stuck with how to edit, add or delete from the structure I am currently using.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/thrprojectss.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Shot%202019-01-09%20at%2012.58.08%20PM.png?alt=media&token=0e9d6b26-d9c7-4f95-853a-f0ad50d0e096

I know I can create a collection of for features and a different collection for comments but as the project will need all data at once i am trying to get them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
features (collection)

---- featureID (document)

-------- featureAuthor (field)

-------- featureVersion (field)

-------- comments (subcollection)

------------ commentID (document)

---------------- commentText: 'this is supperb!' (field)

---------------- commentUserID: 'someUserID' (field)
```

And so on... Would that work for you?